# table view is not loading data

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am running the following code, and have a `UITableView` nested within a `UIViewController`.  The code should be using a `nib` to populate the rows, but for some reason nothing shows up when the `UITableView` loads.  Below is the following class associated with the `UIViewController` that has an embedded `tableview`.  Does anyone know why this may not be loading?

**Code I have tried:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Today: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    var anArray: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "ScheduleCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        self.myTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        self.myTableView.reloadData() //<<<<<<<<<<<<< RELOADS TABLEVIEW

    }//viewDidLoad() ends here


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return the count of the number of groups
        return anArray.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ScheduleCellTableViewCell

        let val = indexPath.row

        cell.testLabel.text = anArray[val]

        return cell
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 160.0
    }
}
```

Comment: did you checked your forCellReuseIdentifier ?

Comment: Delegate and Datasource initialised ?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView! {
  didSet {
   myTableView.delegate = self
                myTableView.dataSource = self
  }
 }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to `reloadData()` for `UITableView` on `viewDidLoad()`.

connect `UITableView` `dataSource and delegate` in `UIViewController` of the `referencingOutlets`. Like as below,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `UITableview` delegate and `datasource` assign properly from `storyboard` if not then assign them into your `viewDidLoad` function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "ScheduleCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        self.myTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.myTableView.delegate = self
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
        self.myTableView.reloadData() // <<<<<< RELOADS TABLEVIEW

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be in `ScheduleCellTableViewCell`, you have not set the CellIdentifier to be "cell".

Btw, I don't think `self.myTableView.reloadData()` is needed in `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 0):

//connect an outlet for table view

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.datasource = self
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```