# Finding Which Cell Was Clicked and Performing Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I've populated a `UITableView` with names of restaurants using Google Places API. Now, I am trying to perform a segue to a different view while knowing which cell was clicked with IndexPath. I've tried using the `didSelectAtIndexRowPath` function but it's not recognizing the tap/click. It should print out the number to the console. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var myIndex = 0
    @IBOutlet var restuarantsTable: UITableView!
    var restaurantsList = [NSDictionary]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        restuarantsTable.dataSource = self

        let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=26.2034071,-98.23001239999996&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=tacos&key=AIzaSyBRQZV4SOpcJ-icCe9BuZlI48MzONwH5Dw"
        downloadRestaurants(urlString: url) { (array) -> () in
            self.restaurantsList = array as! [NSDictionary]
            // print(self.restaurantsList.count)
            self.restuarantsTable.reloadData()
        }

    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return restaurantsList.count
    }


    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let RCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RCell", for: indexPath)
        //   let imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLArray[indexPath.row])
        //   let imageView = RCell.viewWithTag(350) as! UIImageView

        RCell.textLabel!.text = restaurantsList[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
        // RCell.imageView?.image = restaurantsList[indexPath.row]["photos"] as? UIImage

        return RCell
    }

    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: indexPath)

        print(restaurantsList[indexPath.row])
    }

}
```

Comment: You would have to conform to UITableViewDelegate like you did for UITableViewDataSource, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is a UITableViewDelegate method

Comment: See here , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938900/table-view-is-not-loading-data/44939308#44939308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3**

**Error1:**
You have to add `UITableViewDelegate` `protocol` for using `UITableView` `delegate` methods.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{}
```

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    restuarantsTable.dataSource = self
    restuarantsTable.delegate = self
}
```

**Error 2:**
The `protocol` must be confirm with public. You declared as `private`

change

```
private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath){}
```

to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

***or (below swift 3)***

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath){}
```

Comment: This was it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to conform to `UITableViewDelegate` like you did for `UITableViewDataSource`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is a `UITableViewDelegate` method

Add these lines

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

And in viewDidLoad

```
restuarantsTable.delegate = self
```

I think you would have to set delegate in storyboard as well

[image]

Go to this tab and ctrl+Drag to the viewcontroller to set it as delegate

Comment: How do I go about setting it to delegate? Thanks for the quick response btw!

Comment: The same way you did for dataSource

Comment: didSelectRowMethod is not being called?

Comment: Is that different from didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Sorry, new to Swift.

Comment: No its the same method , is this method being called

Comment: Please see Rajmohan's comment if you are unable to set the delegate in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Modify two things in your code set `restuarantsTable.delegate = self` and then reload your table on main thread as you are making network call which will handle in background thread. So also modify below code.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async({
 self.restuarantsTable.reloadData()
})
```